# Genomics-annotation and curation

Tags: genome

How do we spot INDEL errors in an annotated .fna file of Bacillus? Is there a template / example ?

I've annotated a fasta sequence nucleotide in RAStk and am following apaper on how to further curate it.. It mentions that insertion/deletion (indels) errors were corrected in CLC Genomics Workbench 11 and adjusted, as there was enough depth coverage. I would like to apply CLC genomics work bench to check for the errors in the sequences, but how does one recognise what are errors and what is an error free/ or a corrected file to help identify whether the indel sequences have been modified. can we open the fasta file and identify errors?